# How do i make a system on js,if 5000 players dissapear instantly it gives a warning on a discord channel

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that i tried but it doesnt work

```
let previouscount = 0;
const online = data;

if(online - previouscount >= 5000){
//do this
} previouscount = online;
```

So what is wrong with my codes?

I tried every answers on already asked questions on stackoverflow but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

```
I thinks problem with assigning data. It may be incorrect or may be in object or array form. I recommend you first check type of data with typeof.
   let previouscount = 0;
    const online = data
    // Check null or undefined
    if(online) {
      let dataType = typeof online;
      if(dataType == 'string' || dataType == 'number') {
       if(online - previouscount >= 5000){
        //do this
       } previouscount = online;
      }  
    }
```